# Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles matching an applicable signing identity were found

Tags: ios, xcode

I done flowing step with **Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)**

1) Open Xcode preference,

2) Select the appropriate team,

3) Click the "View Details..".

4) In section "Signing Identities": click on "Reset" for each of them.

5) In section "Provisioning Profiles". Click on "Download All".

6) Click on "Done."

but when i trying to archive then flowing error happing :

> Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles matching an applicable signing identity were found.

Comment: have you created app ID on Developer portal ?

Comment: yes i done that one ..

Comment: you downloaded profiles using Xcode ?

Comment: do you mean provisioning  profiles? if so . yes i  download

Comment: try setting automatic it could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Provide bundle identifier in Project Settings Ex :- com.organisation.abc 
In Build settings tab underCode Signing select the certificate for debug or release mode .
Select provisioning profile also in build settings .

It should help you out .